# Losing a space between an H3 and Paragraph in Outlook (HTML EMAIL)

Tags: html, email, outlook

I'm having an issue with email rendering in outlook. I'm going for this:

```
H3 TITLE

Paragraph copy.
```

But I end up with this

```
H3 TITLE
Paragraph copy.
```

Any ideas? Here is the code I'm using. It renders perfectly fine in any other email client, except for outlook.

```
<table bgcolor="ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="min-width: 100px;" width="100%"> 
<tr>
<td align="left" style="padding: 20px 15px 20px 20px;" valign="top" width="50">
<img alt="" src="URL"> </td> 
<td align="left" style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 0px;" valign="top">
<h3 style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 16px; line-height:18px; font-weight: 400; margin 0px; padding-bottom: 10px; color: #333333;"> 
H3 COPY HERE </h3>
<p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica; font-weight: normal; colorl: #333333; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; margin: 0px;"> PARAGRAPH COPY HERE</p>
```

Comment: From your code alone, it shouldn't but outlook and email styling in general can be tricky. Try changing your `padding-bottom` to a `margin-bottom` instead. It may be with how outlook decides how to display your h3

Comment: Thank you, that actually did the trick!